Questions in college coerce Database project
I am now making a Banking System DB
which is more convenient in the case of the account entity to make it the primary key composite of foreign keys (branch id, client id,service id ,four generated intgers for uniqness)
for context service like loan etc , or make them only normal foreign keys.
if you can provide a more general case where composite key is the best use case
